# Can't create ad group

Tags: google-ads-api

Campaign:

```js
{
  "id": "1709932214",
  "name": "Noah Baumbach",
  "status": "ENABLED",
  "servingStatus": "PENDING",
  "startDate": "20190219",
  "endDate": "20190220",
  "budget": {
      "budgetId": "1730787529",
      "name": "Dominic Schumm",
      "amount": {
          "ComparableValue.Type": "Money",
          "microAmount": "10000"
      },
      "deliveryMethod": "STANDARD",
      "referenceCount": 5,
      "isExplicitlyShared": true,
      "status": "ENABLED"
  },
  "conversionOptimizerEligibility": {
      "eligible": false,
      "rejectionReasons": [
          "CONVERSION_TRACKING_NOT_ENABLED"
      ]
  },
  "adServingOptimizationStatus": "OPTIMIZE",
  "frequencyCap": {
      "impressions": "100",
      "timeUnit": "DAY",
      "level": "CAMPAIGN"
  },
  "settings": [
      {
          "attributes": {
              "xsi:type": "GeoTargetTypeSetting"
          },
          "Setting.Type": "GeoTargetTypeSetting",
          "positiveGeoTargetType": "DONT_CARE",
          "negativeGeoTargetType": "DONT_CARE"
      }
  ],
  "advertisingChannelType": "DISPLAY",
  "networkSetting": {
      "targetGoogleSearch": false,
      "targetSearchNetwork": false,
      "targetContentNetwork": true,
      "targetPartnerSearchNetwork": false
  },
  "biddingStrategyConfiguration": {
      "biddingStrategyType": "MANUAL_CPC"
  },
  "campaignTrialType": "BASE",
  "baseCampaignId": "1709932214"
}
```

When I try to create ad group with below parameters:

```js
{
    campaignId: 1709932214,
    name: 'Jess Hegmann',
    status: 'ENABLED',
    criterionTypeGroup: 'VERTICAL',
    targetAll: false,
    bidAmount: 10000,
    biddingStrategyType: 'MANUAL_CPC',
    biddingStrategyName: 'biddingName 123',
    adGroupType: 'DISPLAY_STANDARD',
    adGroupAdRotationMode: 'OPTIMIZE',
  };
```

Google adwords give me an error:

> Failed: "[OperationAccessDenied.OPERATION_NOT_PERMITTED_FOR_CAMPAIGN_TYPE @ operations[0].operand.biddingStrategyConfiguration.biddingStrategyType; trigger:'DISPLAY']"

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be the reason:

> Starting with v201705, this field cannot be set at the ad group or ad group criterion level to any value other than BiddingStrategyType.NONE.

[Bid Strategy AdGroup Google Ads](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201809/AdGroupService.BiddingStrategyConfiguration)